# React Native babel plugin errors

Tags: reactjs, react-native, babeljs

Error message 'index.js: Cannot use the decorators and decorators-legacy plugin together.

Looking at me devDependencies, seems like I only have one? Can anyone help please?

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.8.3",
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.8.3",
  "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.8.3",
  "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.3",
  "babel-preset-react-app": "^9.1.0",
  "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.6",
  "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
  "eslint": "^6.8.0",
  "jest": "^24.9.0",
  "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.4",
  "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
},
"jest": {
  "preset": "react-native"
},
"babel": {
  "presets": [
    "react-app"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
      {
        "legacy": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

babel.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset",
    "react-native",
    "@babel/preset-flow"
  ],
};
```

Comment: Your babel config should be either in your `babel.config.js` or in your `package.json`, otherwise there might be conflicts since they are two different babel configs. That could be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Removing the duplication has worked, thank you. It is now however throwing me another error: `index.js missing initializer in const declaration` - code was working fine before i started playing around with babel :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replicate the comment that answered your problem;

Make sure to have only one babel config that is either in the `babel.config.js`, or directly within the `package.json` file. Otherwise there might be conflicts between the two different configs.

Comment: Thank you - new to this as you can probably tell :)

Comment: Haha no problem don't worry ;)